# How do I add fillStyle to Path2D? JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This is probably impossible as of the date this question is asked but can `Path2D()` have a `fillStyle` inside of the function?
Example:
`Path2D('M10 10 h10 v15 h -18 Z #ff00ff');`

I know that I can add `ctx.fillStyle = color;` before.

I might ignore the first few people that say I can't just to see who if someone else comes up with an answer unless a proper explanation is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed impossible, and for a few reasons.

Path2D only represents a sub-path, as such, it's only vectors and contains no other information.

The filling and/or stroking is a completely separate operation, made at a different moment and usually even on different hardware than the sub-path construction (GPU vs CPU).

Actually the `fillStyle` and `strokeStyle` do represent infinitely large surfaces, which only get clipped by the current sub-path.
These surfaces even are responding to matrix transforms on their own, which allows us to declare a sub-path with one transformation matrix, fill with an other and stroke with a third one:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
ctx.fillStyle = makePattern("red");
ctx.strokeStyle = makePattern("green");
let angle = Math.PI / 2;
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
// we define our path with normal transforms
ctx.rect( 50, 50, 100, 100 );
anim();

function anim() {
  clear();

  // now we play with transforms
  const cos = Math.cos(angle);
  const sin = Math.sin(angle);
  ctx.setTransform( cos, sin, -sin, cos, 125, 125);
  ctx.translate( -25, -25 );
  
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.scale( cos * 5, cos * 5 );
  ctx.stroke();

  angle += Math.PI/360;
  requestAnimationFrame( anim );
}


// jus make a checkerboard, each rect as 5x5px
function makePattern( color ) {
  const ctx = Object.assign(canvas.cloneNode(), { width: 10, height: 10 })
    .getContext( '2d' );
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.rect(0,0,5,5);
  ctx.rect(5,5,5,5);
  ctx.fill();
  return ctx.createPattern( ctx.canvas, 'repeat' );
}
function clear() {
  ctx.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 );
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="300"></canvas>
```

Not only this, but even for methods like `isPointInFill` and `isPointInStroke`, the current context settings will determine how these methods behave:

```js
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas')
  .getContext( '2d' );

const path = new Path2D();
path.rect(50, 50, 50, 50);


ctx.lineWidth = 1;
console.log( 'with lineWidth 1',
  ctx.isPointInStroke( path, 46, 46 ) ); // false

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
console.log( 'with lineWidth 10',
  ctx.isPointInStroke( path, 46, 46 ) ); // true

ctx.scale( 0.1, 0.1 );
console.log( 'after scaling down',
  ctx.isPointInStroke( path, 46, 46 ) ); // false

ctx.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0 );
console.log( 'after resetting the transform',
  ctx.isPointInStroke( path, 46, 46 ) ); // true

ctx.setLineDash( [ 50, 50 ] )
console.log( 'after setting the line dash',
  ctx.isPointInStroke( path, 46, 46 ) ); // false
```

As you can see, a lot of parameters can change how the path will get rendered / used by different APIs. Having all these settings on the Path2D instance itself would make it for an object as heavy as a 2D-Context and that's not what we want:
The Path2d interface is made lightweight on purpose, so that we can store a lot of these, and we can use it as fast as possible. You can still try to make a point with a solid use-case to the [whatwg](https://github.com/whatwg/html) so they consider adding something like this to the specs, but I strongly doubt they will...